# Numeric to datetime (yymmddhhmiss) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, numeric

I have numeric format of date `20001016083256` and I want to convert it into `datetime` format something like `yymmddhhmiss`.

Expected result is

```
2000-10-16 08:32:56
```

Is that possible in SQL Server?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

This kind of transformation is a bit arduous in SQL Server, but this works:

```
select convert(datetime, left(convert(varchar(255), str), 8)) + convert(datetime, stuff(stuff(right(convert(varchar(255), str), 6), 5, 0, ':'), 3, 0, ':'))
from (values (20001016083256)) v(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

@[Gordon Linoff's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54654764/325521) will work for this particular case, but if you are looking for a generic way to parse and convert different types of string values into datetime values, then here's a table-valued function that does it.

**NOTE:** I didn't write it -- Gianluca Sartori did. The author credit is inline in the code, and in the link below.

I know it looks like a lot of code, but the performance is supposedly not an issue. Also it's a generic function that can handle all kinds of custom date string formats.

You can [view the original code with examples here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/88152/).

I created this function in my `tempdb`, ran it for your particular use case and got the correct results.

[image]

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Gianluca Sartori - @spaghettidba
-- Create date: 2011-10-14
-- Description: Parses a date from its string
--              representation, using the supplied
--              format string.
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[parseDate](@date AS varchar(50), @format_string varchar(50))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
    WITH
    -- ================================================
    -- Build 4 rows
    -- ================================================
    fourRows (N) AS (
        SELECT 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 3
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 4
    ),
    -- ================================================
    -- build a small 64 rows tally table
    -- ================================================
    cteTally (N) AS (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
        FROM fourRows AS A
        CROSS JOIN fourRows AS B
        CROSS JOIN fourRows AS C
    ),
    allowedTokens (code, tokenGroup) AS (
        SELECT code COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, value
        FROM (
                      SELECT 'YYYY', 'YEAR'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'YY',   'YEAR'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'Y',    'YEAR'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'MMMM', 'MONTH'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'MM',   'MONTH'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'M',    'MONTH'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'DD',   'DAY'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'D',    'DAY'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'HH',   'HOUR'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'H',    'HOUR'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'hh',   'HOUR'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'h',    'HOUR'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'mm',   'MINUTE'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'm',    'MINUTE'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'ss',   'SECOND'
            UNION ALL SELECT 's',    'SECOND'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'fff',  'MILLISECOND'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'f',    'MILLISECOND'
            UNION ALL SELECT 'tt',   'AMPM'
            UNION ALL SELECT 't',    'AMPM'
        ) AS susbst (code, value)
    ),
    allowedDelimiters (delimiter) AS (
                  SELECT ' '
        UNION ALL SELECT '-'
        UNION ALL SELECT '/'
        UNION ALL SELECT '.'
        UNION ALL SELECT ':'
        UNION ALL SELECT ','
    ),
    -- ================================================
    -- make the parameter case-sensitive
    -- ================================================
    formatStringCS (format_string) AS (
        SELECT @format_string COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
    ),
    inputStringCS (input_string) AS (
        SELECT @date COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
    ),
    -- ================================================
    -- join the format string to the tally table
    -- and add some rankings to identify the "islands"
    -- ================================================
    tokenizedFormatString AS (
        SELECT *,
            subGroupId =
                DENSE_RANK() OVER(
                    ORDER BY C, _subGroupId
                ),
            delimitedGroupId =
                DENSE_RANK() OVER(
                    ORDER BY isDelimiter, _delimitedGroupId
                )
        FROM (
            SELECT N,
                SUBSTRING(format_string, N, 1) AS C,
                _subGroupId =
                    N - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                        PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(format_string, N, 1)
                        ORDER BY N
                    ),
                _delimitedGroupId =
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                        ORDER BY N
                    ) -
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                        PARTITION BY CASE WHEN AD.delimiter IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
                        ORDER BY N
                    ),
                isDelimiter = CASE WHEN AD.delimiter IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
            FROM cteTally AS TALLY
            CROSS JOIN formatStringCS AS FMT
            LEFT JOIN allowedDelimiters AS AD
                ON delimiter = SUBSTRING(format_string, TALLY.N, 1)
            WHERE N <= LEN(@format_string)
        ) AS fs
    ),
    -- ================================================
    -- join the input string to the tally table
    -- and add some rankings to identify the "islands"
    -- ================================================
    tokenizedInputString AS (
        SELECT *,
            delimitedGroupId =
                DENSE_RANK() OVER(
                    ORDER BY G, _delimitedGroupId
                )
        FROM (
            SELECT N, C, G,
                _delimitedGroupId =
                        N - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                            PARTITION BY G
                            ORDER BY N
                        )
            FROM (
                SELECT N,
                    SUBSTRING(input_string, N, 1) AS C,
                    CASE WHEN AD.delimiter IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS G
                FROM cteTally AS TALLY
                CROSS JOIN inputStringCS AS INSTR
                LEFT JOIN allowedDelimiters AS AD
                    ON delimiter = SUBSTRING(input_string, TALLY.N, 1)
                WHERE N <= LEN(input_string)
            ) AS in_str
        ) AS in_str
    ),
    -- ================================================
    -- Aggregate groups on format string
    -- ================================================
    groupedFormatString AS (
        SELECT *,
            delimitedGroupStart =
                MIN(subGroupStart) OVER(
                    PARTITION BY delimitedGroupId
                ),
            subGroupCount =
                COUNT(*) OVER(
                    PARTITION BY delimitedGroupId
                )
        FROM (
            SELECT delimitedGroupId,
                subGroupId,
                subGroupLen = COUNT(*),
                subGroupStart = MIN(N),
                C = MIN(C)
            FROM tokenizedFormatString
            GROUP BY delimitedGroupId, subGroupId
        ) AS src
    ),
    -- ================================================
    -- Aggregate groups on input string
    -- ================================================
    groupedInputString AS (
        SELECT delimitedGroupId,
            groupLen = COUNT(*),
            delimitedGroupStart = MIN(N),
            G = MIN(G)
        FROM tokenizedInputString
        GROUP BY delimitedGroupId
    ),
    -- ================================================
    -- Repeat ranking for format string
    -- ================================================
    rankedFormatString AS (
        SELECT *,
            delimitedGroupRank =
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (
                    ORDER BY delimitedGroupStart
                ) ,
            subGroupRank =
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (
                    PARTITION BY delimitedGroupId
                    ORDER BY subGroupStart
                )
        FROM groupedFormatString AS GFS
        LEFT JOIN allowedTokens AS AT
            ON REPLICATE(GFS.C,GFS.subGroupLen) = AT.code
    ),
    -- ================================================
    -- Repeat ranking for input string
    -- ================================================
    rankedInputString AS (
        SELECT *,
            delimitedGroupRank =
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (
                    ORDER BY delimitedGroupStart
                )
        FROM groupedInputString AS GFS
    ),
    -- ================================================
    -- Discover values in the input string
    -- ================================================
    valuedInputString AS (
        SELECT RFS.tokenGroup, dateValues.value
        FROM rankedInputString AS RIS
        INNER JOIN rankedFormatString AS RFS
            ON  RIS.delimitedGroupRank = RFS.delimitedGroupRank
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT
                CASE subGroupCount
                    WHEN 1 THEN
                        SUBSTRING(@date, RIS.delimitedGroupStart, RIS.groupLen)
                    ELSE
                        SUBSTRING(@date,
                                  RIS.delimitedGroupStart +
                                      RFS.subGroupStart -
                                      RFS.delimitedGroupStart,
                                  RFS.subGroupLen)
                END
        ) AS dateValues (value)
        WHERE tokenGroup IS NOT NULL
    ),
    -- ================================================
    -- Verify tokens
    -- This is just to ensure that only one value per group
    -- is specified in the format string, disallowing ambiguity
    -- ================================================
    verifiedTokens AS (
        SELECT tokenGroup, value,
            patternVerify = CONVERT(datetime,
                CASE COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY tokenGroup)
                    WHEN 1 THEN '2000-01-01 00:00:00.000' -- valid format
                    ELSE '2000-5 :00.000' -- random invalid format
                END,
                121)
        FROM valuedInputString AS VIS
    ),
    -- ================================================
    -- Collapse all tokens in a single line
    -- ================================================
    pivotedTokens AS (
        SELECT year_value      = LEFT('2000',4 - LEN(ISNULL([YEAR],''))) + ISNULL([YEAR],''),
            month_value        = CASE
                                     WHEN ISNUMERIC([MONTH]) = 1
                                         THEN RIGHT('00' + ISNULL([MONTH],''),2)
                                     ELSE [MONTH]
                                 END,
            day_value          = RIGHT('00'   + ISNULL([DAY],''),2),
            hour_value         = RIGHT('00'   + ISNULL(
                                       CASE
                                           WHEN CAST([HOUR] AS int) < 12 AND LEFT([AMPM],1) = 'P'
                                               THEN CAST(CAST([HOUR] AS int) + 12 AS varchar(2))
                                           ELSE [HOUR]
                                       END
                                       ,''),2),
            minute_value       = RIGHT('00'   + ISNULL([MINUTE],''),2),
            second_value       = RIGHT('00'   + ISNULL([SECOND],''),2),
            millisecond_value  = RIGHT('000'  + ISNULL([MILLISECOND],''),3)
        FROM (
            SELECT [YEAR], [MONTH],  [DAY],
                   [HOUR], [MINUTE], [SECOND],
                   [MILLISECOND],    [AMPM]
            FROM verifiedTokens AS VT
            PIVOT (
                MIN(value)
                FOR tokenGroup IN (
                    [YEAR], [MONTH],  [DAY],
                    [HOUR], [MINUTE], [SECOND],
                    [MILLISECOND],    [AMPM]
                )
            ) AS p
        ) AS src
    )
    -- ================================================
    -- Build the output date
    -- ================================================
    SELECT parsedDate =
        CASE
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(month_value) = 1 THEN
                CONVERT(datetime,
                       year_value + '-' + month_value  + '-' + day_value    + ' ' +
                       hour_value + ':' + minute_value + ':' + second_value + '.' + millisecond_value,
                       121)
            ELSE
                CONVERT(datetime,
                       month_value + ' ' + day_value    + ' ' + year_value   + ' ' +
                       hour_value  + ':' + minute_value + ':' + second_value + ':' + millisecond_value,
                       109)
        END
    FROM pivotedTokens
)
```